# XCDatamodeld file disappeared off of computer and now project won't run

Tags: xcode, swift, core-data

Yesterday I had converted my project to Swift 3. I had committed my project to source control before doing this so that I could revert my changes. When I reverted my changes, Xcode crashed and when I had gotten it re-opened, I had a few problems. The biggest one that I am dealing with now is my xcdatamodeld file is gone. I have searched my computer for it, but for some reason it seems to be deleted. So my question is can I create a new xcdatamodel file exactly like my previous one?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What's the version control status? Did you have Xcode open when you reverted?

Comment: Since you had it in source control, why not go get it back from there?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  Data migration .if not select Data model got to editor on top choose create NSManaged object sub class give a new name for your data model done use old data model name.and click net migrate all the entity into that model your data base will get back .